# How to send the size parameter to the CreateVideoWriter function in openCV 2.4, using Python

Tags: python, opencv, tuples

As I understood, in openCV 2.4 the cvSize type is neglected, and one can use a Python tuple instead. When I've tried in the CreateVideoWriter function:

```
import cv2 as cv
writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter('movie', cv.CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, (width,    height))
```

I'm getting this error:
TypeError: CvSize argument 'frame_size' expects two integers.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing cv2 features ( no need for CvSize) with cv functions cv.CreateVideowriter()

Instead use:

```
import cv2
cv2.VideoWriter('movie',cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'),fps,(width,height))
```

Comment: @karlphillip, there are still a few annoying bits, like having to say cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC. But they don't want constants to appear separately in cv and cv2 code.

Comment: Thanks! Any thought how to use it to capture webcam and save it as a movie file?

Comment: see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture